# Emails are not being send on Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

Until last week I could successfully send mails using calls to the MC Rest API, using a Trigger Send.

But now without changing anything, when I make a call to send an email using the follow call:

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:myTriggerSendKey/send
```

The response is the same as always:

```
{"requestId":"xxxxxxxxxxx","responses":[{"recipientSendId":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","hasErrors":false,"messages":["Queued"]}]}
```

and on the trigger send on the UI of MC, the email is queued but after some seconds the email was not send and the completed column don't show it.

I wonder if there is some issue on the MC servers or is under maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that when I try to add a subscriber to a list using a SOAP call, then for some reason the subscriber get with status inactive.
So after I active again then the mails start to be sended again.
By the way, when I add a sender on the list, the server responses with a 200 OK but I can't see the subscriber added.

Thanks anyway!